# How to insert the information of related entity when create(post) in mongooose insertion?

Tags: node.js

How can you relate the database model in mongodb using mongoose? That is, I create a book, I pass all the required values, name, etc, but I want to know how to do if to save the book, also want the information in the book is inserted, for example the id or title. These are the two schemes:

```
var author = new Schema ({
    name: String,
    Biography: String,
    date_of_birth: Date,
    Nationality: String
    books: [{
    Book: {
      title: String,
      ref: 'Book'
    },
    Functions: String
  }],
});

var book = new Schema ({
    title: String
    Pages: Number,
    isbn: String,
    author: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Author"}
});
```

To create the book would do something like:

```
var book = new book ({
    Title: req.body.titulo,
    pages: req.body.paginas,
    isbn: req.body.isbn,
});
s
libro.save (function (err, book) {
    if (err) return res.status (500) .send (err.message);
    res.status (200) .json (book);
});
```

But how do I insert information, for example the id and the title of the book in the author's model?`enter code here`

when i get the book i get all de information but when i get de autor i just have the autor data and not the book created.

Comment: read about many-to-many relationship in mongoose/mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You first get the data of book object and save them with the author id .something like that:

```
var author = new Schema ({
name: String,
Biography: String,
date_of_birth: Date,
Nationality: String
books: [{
Book: {
  type:Schema.ObjectId
  ref: 'Book'
},
title:{
 type:String,
 }
```

}],
});

After creating the book object store the author object id in the book object.And then push the book id and title in the existing author object. then use the mongoose populate,author id can be populate in book document and you can get all the data of the author. And you can also populate the author books array and you can get all the books information of authors.If you need whole code then ask me i write for you .But procedure is very simple

1. First create the object of author with empty book array.
2. Then create the book object and store the reference in of author in book.
3. Then put the update query in author and push the title and ref id of book in the books array of author
4. Use mongoose populate get data according to your requirement and you can author information from book document and get book information from author array.